# Spring MVC: Bad request (parameter missing) on file upload even when required parameters are present

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a file-upload controller with a method that looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"*/*", "application/json"})
public @ResponseBody ScriptUploadResponse upload(@RequestParam("userId") Long userId, @RequestParam("script") MultipartFile file) {
    return scriptService.upload(userId, file);
}
```

This used to work fine in Spring 3 with an XML-based config. I recently moved over to a Java-based config with Spring 4. When I upload a file, I get a `400: Bad request` with the complaint that `userId` has not been provided. But when I look at the request in the browser, this is what I see:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryoJhTJ817NockqUSY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userId"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryoJhTJ817NockqUSY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="script"; filename="script.js"
Content-Type: application/javascript


------WebKitFormBoundaryoJhTJ817NockqUSY--
```

Spring claims:

> HTTP Status 400 - Required Long parameter 'userId' is not present

Why is Spring saying that I haven't provided `userId` when the payload shows that it is present?

**UPDATE**

I've put breakpoints inside `RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java` (an internal Spring class) and I can see that `getParts()` on the `HttpServletRequest` object returns **no** parts at all. I'm not sure why this is happening, but it seems to be the root of the issue. From the browser I can see the request being made, but for whatever reason, the multipart data isn't making it through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. To enable support for multipart files, you have to configure things in a certain way. The documentation for this was frustratingly hard to find and Spring's documentation regarding this seems to be incomplete or only related to XML-based config as well. I am not sure if I'm simply looking in the wrong place or what, but even with Google I was unable to find a single place that explains how to set this up. Anyway, here goes.

You first have to include a bean in your web configuration. I simply added the following to my configuration class (that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`):

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
```

But this is not enough. If you are using Servlet 3.0 and also using a Java-based config for that, you have to configure the dispatcher servlet to support multipart files:

I added the following class to my initializer (that extends `WebApplicationInitializer`):

```
dispatcher.setMultipartConfig(
        new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp", 25 * 1024 * 1024, 125 * 1024 * 1024, 1 * 1024 * 1024)
);
```

The entire method ends up looking like this:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(ApplicationConfig.class, WebConfig.class);

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    //Spring security
    servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain")).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

    //Enable multipart support
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    dispatcher.setMultipartConfig(
            new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp", 25 * 1024 * 1024, 125 * 1024 * 1024, 1 * 1024 * 1024)
    );
}
```

Comment: i only found your answer to be unique , but still it is not working for me.! kindly responsd so i can ask you the issue i am facing.

Comment: @MFaisalHyder Might be worth it to ask a new question.