# how to send empty value for MultipartFile

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, angularjs, spring-mvc

I'm using angularJs and spring 4.0,

My Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody GenericFormResponse execute(
    WebRequest wreq,
    @RequestParam("epName") String epName,
    @RequestParam("ipAddr") String ipAddr,
    @RequestParam("useDefault") String useDefault,
    @RequestParam("certFile") MultipartFile certFile) throws Exception {
    .....................
}
```

my js(angualrJs) code:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("epName", $scope.epName);
formData.append("ipAddr", $scope.ipAddr);
formData.append("useDefault",$scope.defaultCert);
if(!$scope.defaultCert){
    formData.append("certFile", upFile);
}
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "./service/endpoint/add",
    data: formData,
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined }
}).success(svcSuccessHandler)
  .error(svcErrorHandler);
```

My problem is `$scope.defaultCert=false` the POST request is working fine, `$scope.defaultCert = true` i'm getting **Bad request(400)**.

i tried below thing also,

```
if(!$scope.defaultCert){
    formData.append("certFile", upFile);
}else{
    formData.append("certFile", null);
}
```

How do i sent empty `MultipartFile`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two services in controller, and two urls for both

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint/add-with-cert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody GenericFormResponse excecuteWithCert(
        WebRequest wreq,
        @RequestParam("epName") String epName,
        @RequestParam("ipAddr") String ipAddr,
        @RequestParam("useDefault") boolean useDefault,
        @RequestParam("certFile") MultipartFile certFile) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.debug("received request for endpoint creation with certificate");
    GenericFormResponse response = new GenericFormResponse();
    SessionManager sessionMgr = new SessionManager(wreq);
    if(!sessionMgr.isLoggedIn()) {
        response.setSuccess(false);
        response.setGlobalErrorCode("not_logged_in");
        return response;
    }
    ...............
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody GenericFormResponse excecuteWithOutCert(
        WebRequest wreq,
        @RequestParam("epName") String epName,
        @RequestParam("ipAddr") String ipAddr,
        @RequestParam("useDefault") boolean useDefault) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.debug("received request for endpoint creation  without certificate");
    ...............
}
```

in js file:

```
var url = "./service/endpoint/add";
if(!$scope.defaultCert){
    formData.append("certFile", upFile);
    url = "./service/endpoint/add-with-cert";
}       
$http({
method: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: formData,
    transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: {'Content-Type': undefined }
}).success(svcSuccessHandler)
.error(svcErrorHandler);
```

I don't know is this correct approach or not, but it is fulfilled my requirement. working as i expect. Please suggest best answers.

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure properly to enable multipart file upload in Spring 4.

Add the following line to application initializer class:

```
dispatcher.setMultipartConfig(
        new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp", 25 * 1024 * 1024, 125 * 1024 * 1024, 1 * 1024 * 1024)
);
```

Here dispatcher is an instance of ServletRegistration.Dynamic

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109945/spring-mvc-bad-request-parameter-missing-on-file-upload-even-when-required-pa/25110181#25110181) answer for more details.

Comment: if `$scope.defaultCert=false` i can upload file, everything working fine.